# How can I build a dictionary without overwriting?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I am trying to store values in a Python dictionary

```
resname={}
for count, value in enumerate(files):
    resname["serial"]=count
    resname["url"]=value
    resname["name"]=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(value))[0].split(',')[0].split('Data')[1].strip()
    resname.append(resname)

resname
```

But this is not working. I just want to store the full URL as well as a split version of the filename for all the files in a dictionary. But I only get the final file.

```
{'serial': 10,
 'url': '/Users/xtx/DA/data/Data test1.csv',
 'name': 'test1'}
```

How can I store for all the files?

Comment: The code above won't work as `dict` objects don't have an `append` method.

Comment: You may want to rework your global as a **list** of **dict**

Comment: @SeraphWedd Can you provide some more information, please?

Answer (score 2):

The method you have shown above wouldn't work as you are simply writing over the same variable and same key in the dictionary. It would be better if you created a list of dicts instead.

For example

```py
resname=[]
for count, value in enumerate(files):
    temp = {}
    temp["serial"]=count
    temp["url"]=value
    temp["name"]=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(value))[0].split(',')[0].split('Data')[1].strip()
    resname.append(temp)
```

Will achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of dictionaries, as proposed above, is a good solution.

If one of the fields (serial, url or name) works as a unique identifier, you can also store the data as one dictionary, and use that unique identifier as a key in that dictionary (and use another sub-dictionary as the value, whose keys are the other fields).

For example, if the "name" is a unique identifier, you can:

```
resname={}
for count, value in enumerate(files):
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(value))[0].split(',')[0].split('Data')[1].strip()
    sub_dict = {'serial': count, 'url': value}
    resname.update(name: sub_dict)
```

or, using dict comprehension:

```
def name_from_url(value):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(value))[0].split(',')[0].split('Data')[1].strip()

resname = {name_from_url(value): {'url': value, 'serial': count} for count, value in enumerate(files)}
```